# Is there a way or pattern to minify js like `back reference`

Tags: javascript, bundle

I have file structure like below:

```
/js/viewbundle/user/edit/Controller.js
/js/viewbundle/user/edit/Service.js
/js/viewbundle/user/detail/Controller.js
/js/viewbundle/user/detail/Service.js
/js/viewbundle/order/edit/Controller.js
/js/viewbundle/order/edit/Service.js
/js/viewbundle/order/detail/Controller.js
/js/viewbundle/order/detail/Service.js
```

...

I want to bundle the files like this:

```
/dist/viewbundle/user/edit.min.js
/dist/viewbundle/user/detail.min.js
/dist/viewbundle/order/edit.min.js
/dist/viewbundle/order/detail.min.js
```

How could I do that? Is there such a pattern or I need to write scripts to loop the file structure?
Is there a way turn

```
/js/viewbundle/*($1)/*($2)/*.js
```

to

```
/dist/viewbundle/$1/$2/$2.js
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911724/is-there-a-way-or-pattern-to-minify-js-like-back-reference

Comment: what do you want to say?